# how to create a box which is engraved in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, photoshop-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sunken look in photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/sunken-look-in-photoshop)

I saw this effect for input box in ''checkmycolours'' site, it seems really beautiful, but i don't know how to create engraved box.
so if someone know how to create this kind of effect please help me.

http://www.checkmycolours.com/img/input.jpg

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/sunken-look-in-photoshop - Answer by @Alexei has a pretty good video about that.. It is for text, but do the exact same thing on a box with rounded corners and that should do it. ( Which is by the way exactly the same style that I would do it with. )

Comment: This question is already answered. The link that Lollero provided gives you everything you need to know.